# PySpark Convert Column<> to Value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, type-conversion

I'd like to know how to get the value of a calculation done using functions such as `date_add`, `datediff`, `date_sub`, etc. The actual value of it in a variable.

As an example:

```py
start_date = '2022-03-06'
end_date = '2022-03-01'

date_lag = datediff(to_date(lit(start_date)), to_date(lit(end_date)))
```

If I run `date_lag`, the output is: `Column<'datediff(to_date(2022-03-06), to_date(2022-03-01))'>`.

The expected output would be `5`.

I was told by a coworker, I'd have to create a dataframe, apply the column expression and then apply a `collect` to get the value, but I was hoping there would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Just to let you know, the date_lag as is would work when used, but although I've simplified this example so it would also be simple to answer, for the real scenario I still need to have the variable with the actual value of the end calculation

Comment: Why you wan to use pyspark without dataframes?

Comment: Yeah use datetime library instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have used PySpark functions `datediff`, `to_date`, `lit`. They all return a column data type. Columns (also the results of your calculations) *do not exist* unless you add them to a dataframe AND return the dataframe in some way.

So, your colleague was correct telling that first you need to create a dataframe (which will hold your column) and then, since you want your value in a variable, you will have to tell which record from that column you want to take (this can be done using either `collect`, `head`, `take`, `first`,..)

Creating a dataframe with 3 records and adding your column to it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

start_date = '2022-03-06'
end_date = '2022-03-01'
date_lag = F.datediff(F.to_date(F.lit(start_date)), F.to_date(F.lit(end_date)))

df = spark.range(3).select(
    date_lag.alias('column_name')
)
df.show()
# +-----------+
# |column_name|
# +-----------+
# |          5|
# |          5|
# |          5|
# +-----------+
```

Any of the following lines will write the top row's value of your column into a variable.

```py
date_lag_var = df.head().column_name
date_lag_var = df.first().column_name
date_lag_var = df.take(1)[0].column_name
date_lag_var = df.limit(1).collect()[0].column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it using python

```
>>> start_date = '2022-03-06'
>>> end_date = '2022-03-01'

>>> str_d1=start_date.split("-")[0]+"/"+start_date.split("-")[1]+"/"+start_date.split("-")[2]
>>> str_d1
'2022/03/06'
>>> str_d2=end_date.split("-")[0]+"/"+end_date.split("-")[1]+"/"+end_date.split("-")[2]
>>> str_d2
'2022/03/01'

>>> d1 = datetime.strptime(str_d1, "%Y/%m/%d")
>>> d2 = datetime.strptime(str_d2, "%Y/%m/%d")

>>> delta = d1-d2
>>> delta.days
5
```